# Facing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jsp, jpa

I've got this error and not sure why after checking all

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class Entities.Person.Person. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got
>   class Entities.Person.Person

searchPerson.jsp:

```
<%@page import="Entities.Person.Person"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entities.Person.PersonSessionBeanLocal"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatePerson(id) {
        $.post("update.jsp",
                {id: id}
        , function (result) {
            $("#resultDiv").html(result);
        });
    }

    function deletePerson(id) {
        $.post("deletePerson.jsp",
                {id: id}
        , function (result) {
            confirm("Deleted successfully.");
        });

    }
</script>
<%
    try {

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        PersonSessionBeanLocal personBean = (PersonSessionBeanLocal) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/person");

        String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");

        List<Person> resList = personBean.searchPerson(keyword);

        out.print("<table border='1' width='100%'>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<th>ID</th>"
                + "<th>Name</th>"
                + "<th>Description</th>"
                + "<th colspan='2'>Actions</th>"
                + "</tr>"
        );

        for (Person p : resList) {
            //out.print(p.toString() + "<br/>");
            out.print("<tr>"
                    + p.toString()
                    //+"<td><input type='button' name='edit' id='edit' value='Edit' onclick='editPerson(" + p.getId() + ")' style='width:100%'></td>"
                    + "<td><input type='button' name='edit' id='edit' value='Edit' onclick='updatePerson(" + p.getId() + ")' style='width:100%'></td>"
                    + "<input id='hiddenID' name='hiddenID' type='hidden' value='" + p.getId() + "'>"
                    + "<input id='hiddenName' name='hiddenName' type='hidden' value='" + p.getName() + "'>"
                    + "<input id='hiddenDesc' name='hiddenDesc' type='hidden' value='" + p.getDescription() + "'>"
                    + "<td><input type='button' name='delete' id='delete' value='Delete' onclick='deletePerson(" + p.getId() + ")' style='width:100%'></td>"
                    + "</tr>"
            //+ "</table>"
            );
        }
        out.print("</table>");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

%>
```

from here i wanted to perform delete function which lead to deletePeron().

deletePerson.jsp

```
<%@page import="Entities.Person.Person"%>
<%@page import="Entities.Person.PersonSessionBeanLocal"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        PersonSessionBeanLocal personBean = (PersonSessionBeanLocal) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/person");

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

        Person person = personBean.getPerson(id);

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(id);
        p.setName(person.getName());
        p.setDescription(person.getDescription());
        personBean.deletePerson(p);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

and this is the log

```
    Severe:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class Entities.Person.Person. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class Entities.Person.Person
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1135)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.find(EntityManagerWrapper.java:342)
        at Entities.Person.PersonSessionBean.deletePerson(PersonSessionBean.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy454.deletePerson(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jsp.deletePerson_jsp._jspService(deletePerson_jsp.java:64)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class Entities.Person.Person. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class Entities.Person.Person
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1066)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2540)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:951)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
        ... 71 more

update............

i use function from here

PersonSessionBean.java

    package Entities.Person;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import javax.persistence.Query;

    @Stateless
    public class PersonSessionBean implements PersonSessionBeanLocal {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "HelloWorldEE-ejbPU")
        private EntityManager em;



        @Override
        public Person getPerson(int id) {
            try {
                Person p = em.find(Person.class, id);
                return p;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int deletePerson(Person p) {
            try {
                Person person = em.find(Person.class, p);
                em.remove(person);
                return 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return -1;
            }
        }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

After i remove 

> Person person = em.find(Person.class, p);
 from the deletePerson function, the previous error gone but new error came
Severe:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance Entities.Person.Person#7
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaDeleteEventListener.performDetachedEntityDeletionCheck(JpaDeleteEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:916)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:892)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.remove(EntityManagerWrapper.java:323)
    at Entities.Person.PersonSessionBean.deletePerson(PersonSessionBean.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy460.deletePerson(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.deletePerson_jsp._jspService(deletePerson_jsp.java:64)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How your deletePerson function looks like? I guess you call `find` with and instance of Person, but you have to call it with the id

Comment: @Jens updated the function, i call it from the session bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Person person = em.find(Person.class, p);` must be `Person person = em.find(Person.class, p.getId());` in method `deletePerson`.

because the find method expected the id not the whole object

You can also Change the method to use the id as parameter, because you do not Need more informations to delete the object

```
@Override
public int deletePerson(int id) {
    try {
        Person person = em.find(Person.class, id);
        em.remove(person);
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
```